# Broadleaf Commerce - Dynamic Pricing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

I went through the Broadleaf commerce v2.2 documentation/tutorial, specifically Customizing Add Item Workflow and Dynamic Pricing module.

I want to dynamically price a product when it is being added to a cart.

Am I correct in thinking - when a product has to be repriced there can be two approaches to do so ?:

- [Customizing Add Item Workflow using Activity](http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/2.2/Custom-Pricing-Activities.html) - **Updated** *Any modification done to Order Pricing is undone by pricing module. Thus, this approach does not work.*
- [DynamicPricing Filter and Service](http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/2.2/Dynamic-Pricing-Configuration.html)

This can be illustrated:

Approach 1:

```
class DynamicPricingActivity extends BaseActivity{

....
@Override
public ProcessContext execute(ProcessContext context) throws Exception {
CartOperationRequest request = ((CartOperationContext) context).getSeedData();

updatePhonePrice(request.getOrder());

return context;
}
....
}
```

Approach 2:

There are questions regarding instructions in [Dynamic Pricing Configuration](http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/2.2/Dynamic-Pricing-Configuration.html).

- How does the method `MyDynamicSkuPricingServiceImpl # getSkuPrices()` get called?

  *(In documentation it is mentioned that `MyDynamicSkuPricingServiceImpl#getSkuPrices()` will get invoked when getPrice() method gets called, I configured everything as mentioned in the documentation but getSkuPrices() never gets called implicitly)*

**UPDATED** - *I discovered if the HashMap pricingConsiderations is empty in `DynamicPricingFilter`, the `DynamicPricingService#getSkuPrices()` will not be invoked. Thus, for the dynamicPricingService to work, it is essential to have a non-empty HashMap and it will be invoked implicitly.Not sure why it is required...*

**How do I update the pricing of a product added to the cart without persisting this value in the database?**

**UPDATED**

*I was able to add dynamic pricing without having to persist the value in database*:

```
  DiscreteOrderItem orderItem = orderItemService.createDynamicPriceDiscreteOrderItem(orderRequest,          pricingConsiderations);
    orderItem.setRetailPrice(new Money("623.34"));
    orderItem.setSalePrice(new Money("888.888"));
    orderItem.setPrice(orderItem.getSalePrice());
    cart.addOrderItem(orderItem);

    cart = orderService.save(cart, true);
```

***However, the cart total is set to retail price value : 623.34. How do I get the correct total(888.888)**?*

Answer (score 1):

For your last question about overriding the price.    Broadleaf provides methods for overriding the price `(orderItem.setOverrideRetailPrice(), orderItem.setOverrideSalePrice())`.

Without using these methods, the pricing service will reset to the current price on the SKU (or dynamic pricing implementation).

***In all cases, a salePrice that is greater than the retailPrice will be ignored.***

Often when overriding prices, you also want to bypass the discount engine.    You can use the `orderItem.setDiscountingAllowed(false)`.

Since this is typical behavior, a convenience method is also provided `[orderItem.setPrice()]` which will override both the sale and retail prices as well as set discounting allowed to false.

Brian Polster
-- Broadleaf Commerce